# Spring : Autowired Environment is null

Tags: spring

**Spring Version:** 3.2.6.RELEASE

I am trying to access properties in my properties file via `Environment` class in Spring but the autowired `Environemnt` is always `null`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:server.properties")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.repositories")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

     @Autowired
     private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new SpringRestGraphDatabase(env.getRequiredProperty("neo4j.server.url"));
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()             {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import({JMSConfig.class, Neo4jConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=BeansPackageMarker.class)
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

The `@Value` is working fine so I am sure that the Spring is able to locate my properties file and replace the property placeholder with its corresponding value in the properties file correctly

Now I just want to use `Environment` to get property values instead of `${...}` but the `env` is always `null`.

Here's how I am creating the `ApplicationContext`

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. Can you post a stack trace that shows NPE?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired(required = true)
@Override
public void setGraphDatabaseService(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
    super.setGraphDatabaseService(graphDatabaseService);
}
```

Add above method to Neo4jConfig.java